# Django in dock-compose can't see the database : Could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known

Tags: django, postgresql, docker-compose

I am currently on a project based around react in the frontend, django in the backend, postgresql for the database and nginx for the reverse proxy. Everything is linked up with a Docker-compose file.

Right now, I try to link my postgresql database to django.

However every time I try to launch my network with the docker-compose CLI, it fails with the migration of data in the django backend container with the following error:

```
#0 0.697 django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known
```

I do not understand why I have this error. When I try to check if the database is up, it works without any problem:

```
docker-compose up -d db     
Creating network "docker_nginx_django_react_template_appNetwork" with driver "bridge"
Creating db ... done
docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE             COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                       NAMES
_   postgres:latest   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   5 seconds ago   Up 4 seconds   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp, :::5432->5432/tcp   db
```

Here is my docker-compose file :

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  nginx:
    container_name: app_server_conf
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    environment:
      - PUBLIC_URL=127.0.0.1
    volumes:
      - staticfiles:/staticfiles
    networks:
      - appNetwork
    depends_on:
      - backend    
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: db
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - appNetwork
    environment:
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
      POSTGRES_USER: test
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: test
    volumes:
      - postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: pg_isready -U postgres

  backend:
    container_name: backend
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    build:
      context: backend
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    command: "make run"
    networks:
      - appNetwork
    volumes:
      - staticfiles:/app/static/
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    links:
      - db:db

volumes:
  postgresql:
  staticfiles:

networks:
  appNetwork:
    driver: bridge
```

And here is my part of `settings.py` :

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'HOST':'db',
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        'NAME': 'backend_db',
        'USER': 'test',
        'PASSWORD': 'test',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, after many researches on the internet, I am completely lost. What seems weird to me, is I can see the database in the network, like the result below. But even with a hard clean with `docker system prune --force`, it did nothing.

```
docker network inspect docker_nginx_django_react_template_appNetwork
[
    {
        "Name": "docker_nginx_django_react_template_appNetwork",
        ...,
        "Containers": {
            "cb7fdbfc4efe91254e95c02ca680315d488b0c6426ea90b2f682b74bf18eef62": {
                "Name": "db",
                "EndpointID": "endpointid",
                "MacAddress": "mac_address",
                "IPv4Address": "ip_address/20",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        ...
    }
]
```

Comment: The docker-compose and DB settings look correct, so I don't think the issue is here. Can you check to see if you can shell into the django container and reach the db host manually using PSQL? psql -h db -U postgres   . If you can't reach the container from the shell there might be something going on in your DNS

Comment: I had no problem to connect and see what was inside the database container as I saw its content. Unfortunately, when I tried to run the command docker-compose run for the  backend, it resulted in an error. You spoke about a possible DNS problem. Could you explain to me about it?

Comment: It's not just being capable of getting inside the DB container. You'd want to shell into your app_server_conf container and check the ability to establish a connection to Postgres directly from there. I'm betting this doesn't work, and the issue is around how your container networking operates (which also can be affected by the operating system or intranet you're using docker from) https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/

A lot of this depends on the details of the image your Dockerfile is building from. There could be firewalls, custom host files, or other issues.

Comment: So I have found the origin of the problem : in fact, when I try to load the backend container, I do not wait for the database container to be fully launched.

Answer (score 0):

Another try to help:

```
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: db
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - appNetwork
    environment:
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
      POSTGRES_USER: test
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: test
      POSTGRES_DB: backend_db     <--- put NAME of settings.py
    volumes:
      - postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: pg_isready -U postgres
```

Another option I would try is to set the `container_name` to `backend_db`. I do not know how the `container_name` interferes with the environment variable `POSTGRES_DB`.

Comment: The error message implies it's related to networking and not that that database isn't there.

Comment: Yes and I think the reason for it is that in settings.py he defines that the name of the database should be `"backend_db"` but this is nowhere to be found in the docker setup. If it is not looking for the correct name, I agree, the database is there, but can't be found.

Comment: It's a good point, I'm just not sure it'd result in the error given.

Comment: Tried the solution proposed. Unfortunately same problem.

Answer (score -1):

Inside of your settings.py of the django code you have to refine `HOST` and `NAME`.

I am no expert on that but I've had similar struggles. Maybe this helps you? Read about [`HOST`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#host) and [`NAME`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#name).

Sorry for the vague answer but I am not able to provide the plug and play answer. Hope the resources and the hint where the problem most probably lays helps anyways.

Comment: OP's question has `HOST` and `NAME`.

Comment: I know. "refine" means something like "change"